# How do I fix Issue running pexpect-serial example

Tags: serial-port, pexpect

Pexpect serial https://pypi.org/project/pexpect-serial/ throwing an exception while running example.  This in on windows.  How do I fix?

```
import serial
from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect_serial_init_.py", line 1, in
from .serial_spawn import SerialSpawn
File "C:\python36\lib\site-packages\pexpect_serial\serial_spawn.py", line 24, in
from pexpect import spawn
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an alternative project that works on windows
[pexpect-serial-terminal](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect-serial-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

use "import pexpect" instead of "import serial"